# Creating node application with name=value query string

Tags: node.js

I am making a node application that has a search functionality.
The search form resolves to something like this http://localhost/articles?search=searchString which creates a not found error form node because the node route is thus:

```
app.get("/articles/:seach", function(req, res){
//My other code here
})
```

How can I restructure the route to match the url produced by the form get method

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should pull the query param:

```
app.get("/articles", function(req, res){
    //My other code here
    var searchStr = req.query.search;
});
```